# Difference between the PS4 and GoG version of Mount and Blade?

Tags: version-differences, mount-and-blade-warband

I am planning to buy Mount and Blades: Warbands, either the PC version on GoG, or the PS4 version.

Beyond the fact that the PC version has extensions like Napoleonic Wars and Vikings, are there any other differences?

Are those extensions substantial enough for *solo* play that I should choose the PC version for them? Or are they only multiplayer extensions which would be worthless to me?

Comment: This isn't really any answer but I know Napoleonic Wars is multiplayer only. Vikings does have single player if I recall correctly. The real difference is modding on PC since there are complete remakes that make the standard game leaps and bounds better than the vanilla game such as the Floris mod or Gekokoju. Honestly I would say PC is the best bang for your buck.

Comment: I haven't played the console version but I have a feeling that the game is probably more comfortable to control with mouse and keyboard (the combat system with the strike depending on camera angle, aiming bows/crossbows, menus). Plus mod support as Ramirez said (although the vanilla game is already great with a lot of depth). If it makes no difference to you which version to get (Playstation trophies or playing on the sofa for example), I'd go for the PC version as well. Since the game is so old it doesn't even need a good PC.

Comment: @Kodama you bring up a really good point about controls too. Since Mount and Blade Warband a much more realistic type of combat the controls may be a major problem since simply put the controls in Mount and Blade Warband are quite awkward to get used to so playing on PC would be much easier to deal with in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mount and Blade Warband Napoleonic Wars is a **multiplayer only** module for Mount and Blade Warband, so you can easily skip that if you don't care about multiplayer. Viking Conquest **does have single player** and is quite a good module for the game.

There are no discernible differences between the PC version and PS4 version minus the major PC modding scene. The Mount and Blade modding community is quite large and has made tons of different types of modules for your game such as Floris which completely overhauls and adds tons of new mechanics to the vanilla game if you prefer the normal game play. So if you prefer to play single player only Mount and Blade Warband the PC version would most likely be your best bet.